# django: cant import model to a .py on the same path as models

Tags: python, django, models, importerror

I have read everything on SO and all the django docs looking for a solution to this. My models work absolutely fine but i cant import them to my 'getnews.py' file in the same directory as models.py, i can to the views.py and there is absolutely no circular imports!

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class newsurls(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")



class newsblock(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(newsurls)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=2000)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.url)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=2000)
    favi = models.URLField(max_length=2000)
    bgcolor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tcolor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

in views.py: (works)

```
from news.models import newsurls, newsblock
```

getnews.py: (dont work)

```
from news.models import newsurls, newsblock
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/skru/newsshuffle/news/getnews.py", line 3, in <module>
from news.models import newsurls, newsblock
ImportError: No module named news.models
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from news.models import newsurls, newsblock
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle
import random

def news(request):
    newsDatabase = open('/home/skru/newsshuffle/news/storyDb.p', 'r+')
    openData = newsDatabase.read()
    dstory = pickle.loads(openData)
    count = dstory['count']['links']
    story = []
    outstorys = []
    keys = dstory.keys()
    for key in keys:
        if key != 'count':
            story.append(dstory[key]['genre'])
            story.append(dstory[key]['title'])
            story.append(dstory[key]['url'])
            story.append(dstory[key]['image'])
            story.append(dstory[key]['bgcolor'])
            story.append(dstory[key]['via'])
            story.append(dstory[key]['tcolor'])
            outstorys.append(story)
            story = []

    random.shuffle(outstorys)


    lists = newsurls.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:100]
    return render_to_response('news/news.html',
                          {
                          'story_list':outstorys,
                          'count':count,
                          'lists':lists,
                          })
```

filepath:

```
 ├── db.sqlite3
 ├── manage.py
 ├── news
 │   ├── static
 │   │   └── news
 │   │       ├── news.css
 │   │       └── ...
 │   ├── templates
 │   │   └── news
 │   │       ├── allnews.html
 │   │       └── ...
 │   ├── __init__.py
 │   ├── admin.py
 │   ├── dd.py
 │   ├── getPrevDate.py
 │   ├── getnews.py
 │   ├── models.py
 │   ├── storyDb.p
 │   ├── tests.py
 │   ├── urls.py
 │   ├── views.py
 └── newsshuffle
     ├── __init__.py
     ├── settings.py
     ├── urls.py
     └── wsgi.py
```

i have tried every sort of different import 'newsshuffle.news.models' etc..,
added the system path to the system path manually as suggested in other feeds please help!!

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "newsshuffle.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

added this because most other posts on SO point to setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE having to be set manually bur as you can see it already is

Comment: if it's in the same directory why not simply `from models import xyz` ?

Comment: Well, if what you described is true, it is really weird. At this point I would do is that I will create brand new file in the same directory as getnews.py and add only one line "from news.models import newsurls, newsblock". See if that works. If it doesn't work, it means there is something special in your views.py; if it does work, it means there is something wrong in your getnews,py. Regardless which one, start copying code, piece by piece, from the file which has issues into your file and try to find point where the issue is.

Comment: @ PepperoniPizza from models import newsurls, newsblock gets:  ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Comment: @ Jerry Meng  thanks, i created a new file in the same directory and no joy.. adding views.py to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that directory structure, your import should be working.

How about trying a relative import instead? In both `views.py` and `getnews.py` this *should* work:

```
from models import ...
```

Comment: @ Jamie Cockburn : no they're in the same directory, so news contains both views.py and getnews.py aswell as models.py and __init__.py . but already did try from newsshuffle.news.models import...

Comment: @joeskru in that case, `from news.models import ...` shouldn't work from `views.py` either.  Perhaps you should add the relevant parts of your directory structure to your question in a similar manner to my answer, then we can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @ Jamie Cockburn updated the original post, should of really included it in the first place sorry#

Comment: there's no need to add the contents of 'getnews.py'  as i've tried it with nothing other than the import in ther btw

Comment: tried from models import ... got this traceback: ... ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Comment: That means the import itself is working.  That issue is to do with how you're doing the import. Django requires that the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` be set so it can find your settings.py. How is it you are invoking this script? You should be using manage.py.

Comment: its a scheduled task from pythonanywhere.com that i host with. added manage.py

Comment: Well that makes sense then.  What command exactly is it that is being run?

Comment: i dont understand? in getnews?

Comment: what getnews does is scrape links and packs it into a json file in the same directory. this all works fine but i want to use a django model instead of the json file, the script works fine but how can i use manage.py?

Comment: it just 'runs' getnews.py

Comment: okay, you can't just use getnews.py like that if it imports something from django.  It must be run properly, with the proper django context.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#writing-custom-django-admin-commands for info on how to do that.

Comment: completely sorted it.. custom management commands are awesome!! #thanks again

Answer (score 1):

have You tried that?

```
from .models import newsurls, newsblock
```

Please also read about PEP8 http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ cause Your code is not formatted correctly.

EDITED: I see that You trying to do that but without '.' sign. Please note that before models is '.' like that .models

Comment: thanks szymanskilukasz still get an error:                 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                       
  File "/home/skru/newsshuffle/news/getnews.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                     
    from .models import newsurls, newsblock                                                                                              
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package